# Get ID from Corrent Context CRM Online

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-online

I need the id of an incident when I'am closing it .
I use a Plugin to Create a Article After close an Incident But i need the id of the incident to retrive information from that incidente.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this may help you.

```
Guid entityid = Guid.Empty;

if (context.MessageName == MessageName.Close)

{

DynamicEntity entity = context.InputParameters[ParameterName.Target] as DynamicEntity;

string keyfieldname = string.Format("{0}id", entity.Name);

if (entity.Properties.Contains("activityid"))

keyfieldname = "activityid";

entityid = ((Key)entity[keyfieldname]).Value;

}
```

Reference : http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8776e1b-5b80-480d-8ce7-d4e61e3cc3bb/get-current-record-id-using-plugin?forum=crmdevelopment